# Get product ids after import data finish

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer, import

I want get Product Ids after import product using csv file.

When I go following menu `System > Import/export > Import` and import`*.csv` file of products and when finish import data one event called `catalog_product_import_finish_before` this event is in `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php`.

This event work but not getting `ids(entity_id)` of product after imported.

Any one help me where I am going wrong ?

my **app/code/local/Test1/Module1/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test1_Module1>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Test1_Module1>
    </modules>
         <adminhtml>
              <events>
                <catalog_product_import_finish_before>
                    <observers>
                        <test_module1_catalog_product_import_after>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>module1/observer</class>
                            <method>afterImportProductData</method>
                        </test_module1_catalog_product_import_after>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_import_finish_before>
             </events>
          </adminhtml>
</config>
```

this is defined code in **app/code/local/Test1/Module1/Model/Observer.php**

```
public function afterImportProductData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getAdapter()->getData());
        die('die');
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please post the full config.xml file. Youre using 'marketplace/observer' as the observer class name but are your models configured to be using 'marketplace' in the config.xml?

Comment: sry its other code pasted.I revert back and corrected code ..see again and help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following code inside the config tag of your config.xml:

```
<models>
    <module1>   
        <class>Test1_Module1_Model</class>
    </module1>
</models>
```

Then to get the product Ids you can use the following piece of code in your observer:

```
$adapter = $observer->getEvent()->getAdapter();
$affectedEntityIds = $adapter->getAffectedEntityIds();
```

Comment: But I want to fetch new product ids which after imported it creates.

Comment: Observer working properly but any method to get in observer method product ids after imported data  ?

Comment: @test see my edited answer

Comment: What a solution.Your solution is flexible.2 min ago I found solution to override app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php file and  get entitiy_ids from _saveProductEntity function line number 1271 to get entity_ids from foreach loop. $newId is new entitiy_id of new product.Thanks again thank you thank u thank u.

Comment: Your solution is flexible than me. thank you for saving my time

Comment: @test no worries glad it helped ;)

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the `getAffectedEntityIds` method would return all IDs of imported products, new or existing.  I want to trigger upon creation of new items only, is there an easy way to do this?  I'm thinking I'll need to capture the data before the import, find the ones that don't yet exist, and save them for later.  But it would be a lot easier if there were something similar to this that would return the newly created items.  Is this possible?